# How to have void functions in phantomJs

Tags: syntax, phantomjs

Writing some helper functions to use phantomJs as our testing framework, is there any way to make 'void' functions... or to make phantomJs ignore the return value somehow?

```
var mod = require('./mymod.js');
mod.doStuff();

>> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

For convenience sake, is there any way to accomplish this? or a good reason why i shouldn't?

the method exists fine. it's just a method that triggers something. So there's nothing in the design the merits a return value for it.

if I do `var ignore = mod.doStuff();` all is fine. But as I said, for convenience...

i think it tries to evaluate all statements. maybe i'm just used to the lazy parsers that ignore data types on the execution level.

Comment: I think you're confused--what is a "void function" anyway? Here problem is that the `mod` object has no `doStuff` property. You want to silently skip over function calls on undefined objects? Try `if(mod.doStuff){mod.doStuff();}`. The basic question is why are you trying to call an undefined function. This has nothing to do with 'ignoring the return value somehow'.

Comment: it does have the method. if I do `var ignore = mod.doStuff()` it works fine. Sorry i wasn't clear. let me update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible that `mod.doStuff()` would generate an error when `var ignore=mod.doStuff();` does not. There is some other problem, which maybe could be tracked down if you'd post your entire code. Start with the basics: put a breakpoint at the line in question, and when it stops there, examine the value of mod.doStuff and make sure it's a function, etc. etc. In order to do this with phantomJS, google for "phantomJS remote debugging", which will tell you about the `--remote-debugger-port` option, so you can open a web browser to `http://localhost:port` and debug using standard approach.

Comment: i think this is correct, may be something in my code. even though i'm not getting parser errors in the remote debug... and jslint gives me nothing

Comment: i had export instead of exports written some 100 lines after that function :/ after fixing it the complains went away.